# Comando en Linux

Tags: linux

Necesito crear un archivo, asignandole por contenido un listado de los comandos del sistema operativo LINUX.

Tengo dicha pregunta en un parcial y no se como se resuelve. Alguien que me pueda dar una mano? Se agradece info!

Comment: Hola, llevas algo de tiempo en el sitio considera revisar [ask] para formular preguntas en el sitio, saludos.

Comment: `echo 'listado de comandos del sistema'  >> archivocreado`

Comment: Estimado; Le paso un ejemplo
uname -a >> versionso.txt después puede ver el contenido del file:
more versionso.txt Espero que sea de utilidad

Comment: Las preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo. Lee [ask] y [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](/help/on-topic) para más información.

Comment: @MarianoLnx ese comando devolvería la información del sistema (OS, versión, formato) y no la lista de comandos del sistema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta usar el comando que quieres seguido `>` y el nombre del archivo en donde se almacenara los resultados del comando, el archivo lo creara el sistema, intenta algo como:

```
help > archivo.txt

ls > archivo2.txt
```

y se creara un archivo en la ruta donde abriste la consola de comandos.

Answer (score 2):

Para comenzar con el comando `echo` podemos almacenar algo en un archivo.
Por ejemplo: `echo 'hola mundo' > archivo.txt`

En este caso si queremos almacenar una lista de palabras, tenemos que indicar a `echo` que al final de una palabra debe haber un salto de línea y luego la siguiente palabra, así sucesivamente.
Para ello usaremos el comando `echo` pero con la opción `-e` y `\n` para indicar un salto de línea.

Entonces podemos almacenar una lista de palabra así:

```
echo -e "palabra1 \n palabra2 \n palabra3" > archivo.txt
```

En tu caso reemplazarías las palabras por comandos del sistema operativo.

Answer (score 0):

No entendí bien tu pregunta, ¿Tienes ese listado? ¿Deseas generar ese listado y luego escribirlo en un archivo?

Se me ocurren al menos dos maneras de hacerlo.

### compgen (la más sencilla pero quizás no la mejor).

Con el *built-in* `compgen` puedes generar todo un listado de palabras según las opciones.

Si quieres los comandos que tengas disponibles, utiliza

```
compgen -c > lista_comandos.txt
```

Si también quieres los *built-in* de `bash`

```
compgen -bc > lista_comandos.txt
```

Si también quieres las palabras reservadas de `bash`

```
compgen -bkc > lista_comandos.txt
```

Digo que quizás no es la mejor porque hay tokens reservados como `{` que no son programas o comandos.

### Usando `PATH`.

`bash` tiene una variable de entorno llamada `PATH` posee el nombre de cada carpeta, separada con dos puntos ":", en donde buscará archivos ejecutables.

En ese caso, podemos buscar en cada carpeta

```
printf "$PATH" | xargs -d : -I {} find {} -type f -executable > lista_comandos.txt
```

Con este comando debería ser suficiente. El contenido de la variable `$PATH` lo usa para "alimentar" la entrada del comando `xargs`, este programa es casi mágico, en el cual con el parámetro `-d :` pone como delimitador los dos puntos ":" y con `-I {}` indica que se podrá usar el campo capturado con los caracteres `{}` (cada campo capturado será el nombre de cada carpeta en la variable `$PATH`); entonces usaremos ese campo capturado (el nombre de la carpeta) y buscaremos con `find` únicamente los archivos regulares, con el parámetro `-type f` y de tipo ejecutable con el parámetro `-executable`.

Con esto tenemos cada ejecutable de cada carpeta registrada en la variable `$PATH` (te recuerdo que ahí es donde se buscan los comandos).

Comment: "_No entendí bien tu pregunta, ¿Tienes ese listado? ¿Deseas generar ese listado y luego escribirlo en un archivo?_" Tu primera frase indica que la pregunta es demasiado amplia y no está clara del todo, en lugar de responderse habría sido mejor dejar un comentario o votar por cerrar. No digo que borres la respuesta (que es válida, completa y detallada), pero deberías leer [answer] (en concreto la sección de qué preguntas deberíamos evitar responder).